# How to implement vertical sliding show/hide div with expndable main div

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to implement a panel like following images using bootstrap:

[image]
Figure 01: side bar in full state.

The left panel will have a show/hide button.
On hide, it will slide upward to its minimum state (figure 2).
the main div container would increase in size and fill the empty space in left.
All resizes need to be with transition animation.

[image]
Figure 02: Side bar in minimum state.

Any help/tips, how can  achieve that?

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use `float` with `overflow: hidden`:

```css
.parent{
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.panel{
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: #EFEF66;
}
.navigation{
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #EF66EF;
}
.main{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  clear: right;
  background-color: #66EFEF;
}
```

```html
<div classs="parent">
  <div class="panel">Side Panel</div>
  <div class="navigation">Navigation</div>
  <div class="main">Main section</div>
</div>
```

In the above snippet, you have it as the primary state. Now if you want the `panel` to stretch down, just force a `height` for `panel`:

```css
.parent{
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
}
.panel{
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #EFEF66;
}
.navigation{
  float: right;
  width: 80%;
  background-color: #EF66EF;
}
.main{
  overflow: hidden;
  width: auto;
  clear: right;
  background-color: #66EFEF;
}
```

```html
<div classs="parent">
  <div class="panel">Side Panel</div>
  <div class="navigation">Navigation</div>
  <div class="main">Main section</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that you are not showing what you got so far I'ts really hard to help you.

[Check this codepen for a little help with the HTML structure](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gPdVvj)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="col-xs-3 header-left">
      Hi
    </div>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="app-body">
  <div class="col-xs-12 inner-body"></div>
</div>
```

**SCSS**

```
.header{
  height: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
  position: relative;
  .header-left{
    height: 290px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
  }
}
.app-body{
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 25%;
  .inner-body{
    height: 100%;
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

You should be able to get to what you want starting with the code I gave you. But have In mind that my code shows the slide-down state. You'll have to add animations and JS events to achieve the effect you want.